# GGPlot - Moving facet_wrap y labels to left and making text horizontal

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried existing answers but none are giving me the result I am looking for. Would really appreciate some help. I want to make a chart like the below with the y-axis showing Family and Species:

[image: What I'm aiming for:]
I've used `facet-wrap` but this puts lines between the families, squashing them, and you cannot read the family names. I'd like to position them as "Group A, Group B" in the given example (ie, to the left of the species names, horizontal text and with lines between them instead of gaps in the chart).

Here's what I've created so far:.

[image: Without facet_wrap on Y=axis, I'd like to retain this spacing]

And here is with `facet_wrap` by Family on the Y-axis:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
  ggplot(lower[lower$Value != 0,], aes(x=Sample, y=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Value, alpha = 0.75)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabels, drop = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=7),
        legend.position = "right",
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_alpha(guide = "none") +
  facet_grid(Family ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  scale_size_area("Frequency", limits = c(1, 20), breaks = c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20),
                  labels = c("One sighting", "Rare", "Uncommon", "Common", "Very common"))
```

And sample data below.

EDIT: Have removed the spacing and switched the Y-axis as per Roman's comments. Getting there. Just need to add separating lines between the families and rotate the text so it's horizontal. New code:

```
    ggplot(lower[lower$Value != 0,], aes(x=Sample, y=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Value, alpha = 0.75)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabels, drop = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=7),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "lines"),
        legend.position = "right",
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_alpha(guide = "none") +
  facet_grid(Family ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "y") +
  scale_size_area("Frequency", limits = c(1, 20), breaks = c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20),
                  labels = c("One sighting", "Rare", "Uncommon", "Common", "Very common"))
```

And new plot (planning to fix vertical spacing/overlaps next):

[image: New plot]

Many Thanks

{structure(list(Year = c("1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020"), 
    Sample = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
    5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 
    8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 
    4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
    7L, 4L, 8L), .Label = c("Developed_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_1992", 
    "Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Greatest_frequency_1992", "Developed_zone_2020", 
    "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Greatest_frequency_2020"
    ), class = "factor"), Value = c(10L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    10L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 
    5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 
    10L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 20L, 
    0L, 20L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 5L), Family = structure(c(16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("Laridae", 
    "Ciconiidae", "Phalacrocoracidae", "Threskiornithidae", "Ardeidae", 
    "Accipitridae", "Tytonidae", "Strigidae", "Upupidae", "Coraciidae", 
    "Alcedinidae", "Meropidae", "Picidae", "Falconidae", "Psittaculidae", 
    "Laniidae", "Corvidae", "Alaudidae", "Pycnonotidae", "Hirundinidae", 
    "Phylloscopidae", "Acrocephalidae", "Cisticolidae", "Leiothrichidae", 
    "Sylviidae", "Sturnidae", "Turdidae", "Muscicapidae", "Nectariniidae", 
    "Ploceidae", "Estrildidae", "Motacillidae", "Emberizidae"
    ), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(69L, 69L, 69L, 
    69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 
    68L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
    66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 
    64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 
    63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L), .Label = c("142. Black-headed bunting (1177)", 
    "141. Rustic bunting (1174)", "140. Striolated bunting (1167)", 
    "139. Caucasian water pipit (1100)", "138. Tree pipit (1093)", 
    "137. Tawny pipit (1090)", "136. Richard's pipit (1086)", 
    "135. White wagtail (1076)", "134. Grey wagtail (1075)", 
    "133. Western citrine wagtail (1073)", "132. Blue-headed wagtail (1060)", 
    "131. Scaly-breasted munia (1046)", "130. Indian silverbill (1045)", 
    "129. Red avadavat (1042)", "128. Streaked weaver (1033)", 
    "127. Yellow-throated sparrow (1024)", "126. House sparrow (1007)", 
    "125. Purple sunbird (1005)", "124.  Red-tailed wheatear (997)", 
    "123. Hume's wheatear (988)", "122. Pied wheatear (978)", 
    "121. Eastern black-eared wheatear (976)", "120. Desert wheatear (975)", 
    "119. Isabelline wheatear (973)", "118. European stonechat (963)", 
    "117. Whinchat (960)", "116. Western blue rock thrush (957)", 
    "115. Common rock thrush (955)", "114. Common redstart (948)", 
    "113. Central Asian black redstart (945)", "112. Red-breasted flycatcher (938)", 
    "111. Semi-collared flycatcher (937)", "110. Red-spotted bluethroat (921)", 
    "109. Spotted flycatcher (911)", "108. Rufous-tailed scrub robin (908)", 
    "107. Black-throated thrush (899)", "106. Superb starling (884)", 
    "105. Wattled starling (883)", "104. Common starling (882)", 
    "103. Common myna (875)", "102. Menetries's warbler (849)", 
    "101. Asian desert warbler (824)", "100. Desert whitethroat (834)", 
    "99. Lesser whitethroat (833)", "98. Arabian babbler (827)", 
    "97. Graceful prinia (818)", "96. Upcher's warbler (804)", 
    "95. Eastern olivaceous warbler (802)", "94. Marsh warbler (798)", 
    "93. Indian reed warbler (787)", "92. Great reed warbler (784)", 
    "91. Leaf warbler sp.", "90. Common chiffchaff (773)", "89. Willow warbler (770)", 
    "88. Red-rumped swallow (746)", "87. Common house martin (741)", 
    "86. Pale crag martin (740)", "85. Eurasian barn swallow (735)", 
    "84. Sand martin (731)", "83. White-spectacled bulbul (724)", 
    "82. Red-vented bulbul (725)", "81. White-eared bulbul (724)", 
    "80. Crested lark (702)", "79. Black-crowned sparrow-lark (696)", 
    "78. Brown-necked raven (662)", "77.  Masked shrike (630)", 
    "76. Great grey shrike (623)", "75. Turkestan shrike (619)", 
    "74. Daurian shrike (618)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
72L), class = "data.frame")}

Comment: can you update your example code including more than one family. try to add `switch="y"` in the facet function. remove space by panel.spacing in theme

Comment: @Roman. Doh. I've expanded the sample data. I'll take a look at switch="y" and panel.spacing. Thanks

Comment: @Roman. "swtich="y" and panel spacing were easy, thanks! I've updated the code and new plot in my post.

Comment: Putting this in your theme will make the strip text horizontal `strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0)`. I don't think ggplot2 has the line seperators you are looking for.

Comment: @teunbrand. Thanks! I've managed that. Shame about the dividing lines though - the example at the top seems to use them. I'll have a further play.

Comment: So one of two things can be true; (1) there exists a package or code somewhere that allows these dividing lines and we don't know about it or (2) it is a customization made downstream of plotting (e.g. grid/gtable or illustrator/gimp). It got me thinking that it should be possible to make a theme element that does partial rectangles, which I filed as an idea here: https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues/13, but I don't know when I have time to work on this.

Comment: (1) doesn't sound likely in that case :) Another option (that I don't think already exists) is to allow for nested / multiple labels on the axes. I didn't actually want to use facet_wrap due to my space limitations but it was the only way I could find to have both family and species labelled. Thanks for your help!